# Inverted X axis in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

The X axis seems inverted in my OpenGL test program...

The red cube is placed at (0,0,0), the white one at (0,0,1) and the blue one at (1,0,0), and yet it appears at the left of the red cube.

[image]

I used [this code](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/) for the projection/view matrix, so I don't think it comes from there... Is there any OpenGL parameter that might do that?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of the matrices when the camera is at (1.57, 4.54, -1.23) with 6.09rad as horizontal angle and -0.97rad as vertical angle :

**Projection matrix:**

```
 1.34  0     0     0
 0     1.79  0     0
 0     0    -1    -1
 0     0    -0.02   0
```

**View matrix:**

```
-0.98  -0.15   0.1    0
-2.14   0.56   0.82   0
-0.18   0.81  -0.55   0
 1.32  -1.31  -4.59   1
```

Comment: This are common errors when setting up cameras etc. Where is the camera? What is the green position?

Comment: The green cube is at (0, 1, 0) and the camera at (1,4,-2)

Comment: Can you post for view/proj matrix. The link you posted is also about keyboard input, I assume its from same series of tutorials tho.

Comment: I edited my post with the matrices

Comment: Thanks, sorry I meant the code that builds your matrices. Is it just the same as the tutorial you posted?

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding! Yes, I use the same formulas as the tutorial

Comment: Formulas or Code? Sorry to be pedantic, but good to see how you are creating your MVP mats, and your shader. If they are identical. Then I wonder if you are setting `glFrontFace`

Comment: Same code. I do not use `glFrontFace`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73467/discussion-between-phito-and-philck).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a natural result of the camera position you are using.

Picture a standard right-handed coordinate system:

```
   |y
   |
   |
   |________x
  /
 /
/z
```

In this sketch, x goes from left to right, y from bottom to top, and z towards us.

This means that if you used a camera position with a **positive** z-value, this camera would see the xy-plane in the orientation that corresponds to this sketch. Which in turn means that points with larger x-values are to the right of points with smaller x-values.

Now, if you use a camera position with a **negative** z-value, which is the case in your example, this whole thing turns around. The coordinate system viewed from the camera now looks more like this:

```
       y|
        |  /z
        | /
x_______|/
```

As you can see, from this vantage point, the x-axis now goes from right to left, which means that points with larger x-values are now left of points with smaller x-values.

This is exactly what your rendering shows. The blue cube has larger x-coordinates than the red cube, so it shows up on the left of the red cube when viewed from this direction.

Comment: Ohhh so the Z axis goes that way... So everything was working fine, I just got confused! Thank you