# How do I use a left handed coordinate system for rendering?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, vulkan

I'm trying to setup view, and projection matrices to work with my intended world coordinates and handedness. I'm going for a left handed coordinate system, +X to your right, +Y above you and +Z before you.

Y coordinates are working fine but objects placed in front of the camera (+Z) are showing up behind it, so I have to turn the camera 180 degrees to see them, this was an easy fix as flipping the view matrices' Z did it, but now object are flipped X wise (text is seen as in a mirror). I tried negating each objects Z for their model matrix and that works fine, but I feel there should be another cleaner solution.

My issue is similar to this: [Inverted X axis in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169100/inverted-x-axis-in-opengl), but I couldn't find a proper solution.

This is the projection matrix code.

```
Matrix4 BuildPerspectiveMatrix(const float32 fov, const float32 aspectRatio, const float32 nearPlane, const float32 farPlane)
{
    Matrix4 matrix;
            
    //Tangent of half the vertical view angle.
    const auto yScale = 1.0f / Tangent(fov * 0.5f);

    const auto far_m_near = farPlane - nearPlane;
    matrix[0][0] = yScale / aspectRatio; //xScale
    matrix[1][1] = -yScale; 
    matrix[2][2] = farPlane / (nearPlane - farPlane);
    matrix[2][3] = (farPlane * nearPlane) / (nearPlane - farPlane);
    matrix[3][2] = -1.0f;           
    matrix[3][3] = 0.0f;
    return matrix;
}
```

Scene is setup like this:

Camera is at (0, 0, 0) (center of the world), object 1 is at (0, 0, 2) (2 units forward in front of the camera) and object 2 is at (1, 0, 2) (1 unit to the right and 2 units in front of the camera).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vulkan, like non-legacy OpenGL and DX 11+ are all independent of any chosen "handdedness", that's an artefact of the math library you're using (if any).

As to your actual question, the matrix you're building is right handed because you assign `-1` to `matrix[3][2]`. The left handed version is the same except it has `1` for that location.

Comment: It is actually not correct that the APIs are independent of any chosen "handedness" throughout a graphics pipeline. That point could only be made for everything before NDC space. NDC space has well defined handedness, which is left-handed for OpenGL, and right-handed for Vulkan. See here: https://matthewwellings.com/blog/the-new-vulkan-coordinate-system/ and here: http://anki3d.org/vulkan-coordinate-system/

Comment: That's not what is meant by left or right handedness, that's just what the projection matrix has to output. There still are left and right versions of the perspective matrix for Vulkan.

Comment: I updated my matrix to be left handed as per this blog. https://www.codersblock.org/blog/multiplayer-fps-part-7 (swapping Y and Z) and now Z is how I expect it to be, but every object is inverted along the X axis. I could flip screen X but then that axis wouldn't work how I expect it to.

Comment: Without trying to sound rude, your expectation is on your side, all I can tell you is that algebra is algebra. It is perfectly fine to expect your X axis to be negated, but you need to write that down in your transform matrix chain yourself. One suggestion I would give you is that if you're working with models exported from modelling applications, you can pre-bake any axis negations in the application's export dialog. Otherwise, simply multiply your matrices as needed, it's more than good enough.